# How do I add additional code into the Yocto Kernel from a second git repository?

Tags: yocto

How I can add the wireguard code (https://git.zx2c4.com/WireGuard/) into the root of the kernel-source without having to create a patch file?

Answer (score 0):

You should add wireguard as an out-of-tree module, and you can see in this [manual section](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#working-with-out-of-tree-modules) how to create corresponding recipe.

In poky layer, there are some examples, and you can find [kernel module example](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/meta-skeleton/recipes-kernel/hello-mod/) too.